# libgdx Background TextureRegion repeat

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm new in libdgx developement and also in game developement. I am reading the book "Learning Libgdx Game Development" from Andreas Oehlke and I am trying to develop my own game in parallel. 
I have a problem when I try to add the background. In the book, he uses a color, so it's very simple. But I want to add an image from a texture atlas. The image is to small to recover all the screen, so I want to repeat it. I can't use regBackground.setWrap(TextureWrap.Repeat, TextureWrap.Repeat) because regBackground is not a texture. How i can resolve my problem properly?

```
   public class Background extends AbstractGameObject {

   private TextureRegion regBackground;

   public Background () {
      init();
   }

   private void init () {
      dimension.set(1f, 1f);
      regBackground = Assets.instance.levelDecoration.background;
   }

   public void render (SpriteBatch batch) {
      TextureRegion reg = null;
      reg = regBackground;
      batch.draw(reg.getTexture(), 
            position.x, position.y, 
            origin.x, origin.y, 
            dimension.x, dimension.y, 
            scale.x, scale.y,
            rotation, 
            reg.getRegionX(), reg.getRegionY(), 
            reg.getRegionWidth(), reg.getRegionHeight(), 
            false, false);
   }
}
```

In my Assets class, I have this code to find the region in the texture atlas :

```
     public class AssetLevelDecoration {
         public final AtlasRegion background;

         public AssetLevelDecoration (TextureAtlas atlas) {
             background = atlas.findRegion("background");
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

I progressed in solving my problem. I use the setWrap method to repeat my texture :

```
   public class Background extends AbstractGameObject {

   private TextureRegion regBackground;

   public Background (int width, int heigth) {
      init(width, heigth);
   }

   private void init (int width, int heigth) {
      dimension.set(width, heigth);
      regBackground = Assets.instance.levelDecoration.background;

      origin.x = -dimension.x/2;
      origin.y = -dimension.y/2;
   }

   public void render (SpriteBatch batch) {
      TextureRegion reg = null;
      reg = regBackground;

      Texture test = reg.getTexture();
      test.setWrap(TextureWrap.Repeat, TextureWrap.Repeat);
      batch.draw(test, 
            position.x + origin.x, position.y + origin.y, 
            test.getWidth(), test.getHeight(), 
            reg.getRegionX(), reg.getRegionY(), 
            reg.getRegionWidth(), reg.getRegionHeight()       
            );

   }
}
```

Now, I obtain this, but I just want to repeat my background image (wood square).

http://s24.postimg.org/c1m92ffwx/Capture_du_2013_11_12_15_49_03.jpg

The problem  is that the getTexture() recover the all image and not only my background. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I would just add a comment but I don't have the rep.

To solve the issue of the repeating of the whole texture instead of only the wooden square you have 2 choices. A) separate the textureregion onto a separate texture. B) loop over the to repeat the draw, which should be negligible in terms of performance.

http://badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=8883

Answer (score -1):

a simpler approach will be

```
 batch.draw(imageReference,startX,startY,widthOfScreen,heightOfScreen);
```

batch.draw() is an overloaded method so use only those parameter u need
the syntax is just a pseudo code

MOst importantlu This may give image stretching(depending on image).

Comment: Can you be more specific please.

Comment: batch.draw(reg.getTexture(),0,0,480,800);

//i am amusing your camera height is 800 and width to be 480

// about what part in my answer you need specification sir

Comment: Your code give me a black screen.
If I don't use reg.getRegionX(), reg.getRegionY(), reg.getRegionWidth() and reg.getRegionHeight() no image is displayed.

I don't want to stretch my image I want to repeat it. I think I need to use TiledDrawable but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: U can also write a for loop for drawing

Comment: You are drawing a background or an object for which u need a bounds and other stuffs

Comment: It's just a background (with no bounds)

Comment: sir a approach for this could be like this
take the width and height of image to be multiple of screen size
say cam is 480*800 than take image to be 48*80
then using for loop u can do it

Comment: can uplz tell if ur image is plain or some picture u want to draw again

Answer (score -1):

I have created an introduction to images including repeating texture here: https://libgdx.info/basic_image/

I hope it helps

This creates an image along this line:
[image]