# My frame rate is dropping after loading in thousands of objects, how to handle

Tags: java, libgdx

I am making a copy of Terraria and obviously There is a beneath zone where thousands of "dirt" objects will be loaded. However this causes a heavy drop in my FPS. I have searched the web but I can't find any solutions due to my specific problem. I have tried rendering only 100 blocks and to only render what is in screen however my FPS drops to 20 even when 300 or so blocks are rendered. My game looks like this
(only what is seen is being rendered)

[image]

There are exactly 4 different images and the code to run this looks like this

```
    public void render() {
    fps.log();
    collisionHandler.run();
    // collisionHandler.update();
    player.update();

    camera.update();

    mapGrid.update();

    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL30.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    batch.setShader(null);
    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(background, 0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),
            Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    batch.end();

    mapGrid.drawGrid(renderer);
    batch.setShader(null);
    player.draw(batch, renderer);
    ground.update(batch);
    ground1.update(batch);
    for (int i = 0; i < groundList.size(); i++){
        groundList.get(i).update(batch);
    shader.begin();
    shader.setUniformf("u_resolution", groundList.get(i).getPosition());
    shader.end();
    }
    //batch.setShader(shader);

    for (int i = 0; i < dirtList.size(); i++)
        // update means render*** dirtList consists of dirt objects!
        dirtList.get(i).update(batch);

}
```

I have tried storing these objects in a pool or cache and yet nothing seems to boost the FPS back to 60. Please help any help or direction at all would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: One thing you could do is benchmark your code a bit, that's how I did for my engine. Put useful timers everywhere with helpful text, and print the time for each operation. You may find your bottleneck very fast ! Also I know nothing about what you do (I did mine in C++), but common mistakes are to have a loop that goes too fast, blocking IO somewhere, an algo that could be run once that you run everytime etc! Good luck !

Comment: Thanks I'll look into it! @Pierre

Comment: The `SpriteBatch` can store many drawcalls, before flushing them as one draw call to the GPU. This can boost the performance, as drawcalls are pretty heavy operations. A call to `batch..end()` and `batch.flush()` will flush the things to the GPU. Therefore make sure you only call this methods, when it is really needed. So make sure you don't have to many `batch.end()` calls in your render code.

Comment: From what I can see, you must be calling `batch.begin()` and `end()` inside `ground.update(batch)`, so that is likely the problem.

Comment: Since there are just a bunch of repeated textures, you should use [tile maps](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Tile-maps#loading-tide-maps) instead.

Comment: @Springrbua I tried ur method and it worked I started the batch at the top of render loop and ended at bottom however now my animation won't run and some images are missing

Comment: @Luke you don't have to use only 1 `batch.begin()`-`batch.end()` block, but you just have to reduce the number of blocks as much as possible. So try to remove them one after the other (beginning with the `update(batch)` methods, which are called pretty often). So you might draw the background in one block, the mapgrid in one block and the rest in one block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be better to use a repeating texture or something for big clusters that can be drawn at once. For example, if there is a rectangular cluster made of 10*15 blocks, instead of drawing 150 blocks one by one, just fill the are with the same repeated texture. Break it down to smaller clusters when the player interacts with them.

In the screenshot you posted, all of the dirt blocks can be drawn as a single block. If any of them break, just recalculate big rectangular areas, and draw new smaller clusters.

[Here's an example for repeated textures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19905117/libgdx-background-textureregion-repeat)

Answer (score 0):

How many dirt objects are you trying to render per frame?  If its in the thousands as you say, I would say this is your problem.

Pooling/caching wont fix your framerate here.  It'll only help you with memory management when creating/destroying all those dirt objects.

If you know your way around *GLSL*, you could actually render all those dirt blocks with one pass, instead of thousands.  Thats one solution.